# How to solve Error: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'createLead' property?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

I have written a script that should connect to a secure web service (ws-security). However, when running the script, I'm getting this error:

```
Error: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'createLead' property
```

I'm using this code:

```
<?php
$wsdl = "http://localhost/test/wsdl-src/CRMLeadService.wsdl";
$momurl = "https://integrationdev.momentum.co.za/sales/CRMService/CRMLeadService_v1_0/";

echo "Post to URL: {$momurl}\n";

$username = '817221';
$password = '1234';

//Perform Request
$client = new SoapClient ($wsdl, array('loacation' => $momurl));

$security = array('UsernameToken' => array(
    'Username'=>"$username",
    'Password'=>"$password"
));

$header = new SoapHeader('wsse','Security',$security, false);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

print_r($client);
echo "<br />";

print_r( $client->__getFunctions() ); //Available Function

$params = array(
    'LeadSourceId' => '23627e70-a29e-e211-b8a8-005056b81ebe',
    'AffiliateLeadReference' => '5465546hdfh5sggd52',
    'Title' => '852800018',
    'Initials' => 'MD',
    'PreferredName' => 'Marius',
    'FirstName' => 'Marius',
    'LastName' => 'Drew',
    'PreferredCorrespondenceLanguage' => '852800001',
    'PreferredCommunicationMethod' => '852800000',
    'Campaign' => '',
    'HomePhoneNumber' => '0723621762',
    'BusinessPhoneNumber' => '0723621762',
    'MobilePhoneNumber' => '0723621762',
    'EmailAddress' => 'mdrew@gmail.com',
    'Notes' => 'IMU',
    'ProductCategories' => array('Code' => 'd000083d-229c-e211-b8a8-005056b81ebe')
);

print_r($params);

try { 
    echo $result = $client->__soapCall('createLead',array('parameters'=>$params));
} catch (Exception $e) { 
    $msgs = $e->getMessage();
    echo "Error: $msgs"; 
} 
?>
```

The WSDL and XSD files can be downloaded here:

**http://sdrv.ms/16KC8o4**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: show your soap `Available Function`

Comment: When you run the script, the available function would be: CreateLeadResponse createLead(CreateLeadRequest $parameters)